# Text is not active on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I'm using a W3 schools slideshow template as a starting place, but instead of using dots i'm using text and I have two issues

1: The first image does not load when the page loads. I can get around this by using a class ID and setting it to active but I don't like using this because this creates my second issue

2: When I force the image to load, the text/button for that first slide is not active. Active/Hover is a red color and inactive is grey, and when the page loads with the forced image the text is grey.

Heres my code:

```
<style>
{box-sizing: border-box}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 2px;
  color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  color: #cc3333;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>

    <div style="border-top: 6px solid #cc3333;padding-bottom: 100px; padding-top: 100px" class="row highlight-phone">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="vidrow">
                <div class="vidcolumn slideshow-container">
                    <div id="slide1" class="mySlides">
                        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mySlides">
                        <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mySlides">
                        <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="vidcolumn">
                    <div class="intro">
                        <h2 style="text-decoration:overline;text-decoration-color: #cc3333;">How It Works</h2>
                        <div id="dot" class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)">Learning Paths</div>
                        <br>
                        <span id="dot" class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)">Songs</span>
                        <br>
                        <span id="dot" class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)">Training</span>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-wi-red btn-pill" role="button" href="#">VIEW DEMO</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Image for reference:
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdPIy.png)

How do I fix this?

Comment: You are missing * on your css, and which slideshow are you trying to make? automatic?

Comment: its a manual 3 slide slideshow that activates each slide when they click on the text in the picture

Thanks for that * tip. forgot

Comment: @Squish it seems like I could just call it with javascript, but my knowledge of java is limited. Would that be a good way, and how would that be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, javascript is not java :). Also, I dont think this is a matter of your javascript. Take a look at your image source. The first one contains a url while the other two only contains a local image. This means that this problem comes from you image location.
Fixing methods:

1. Try changing it into the correct path from your local directory.
2. Change all of them into url images just like the first one.

Like this for example:

```js
 var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
  }

  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
      slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  }
```

```css
 *{
    box-sizing: border-box
  }

  .mySlides {
    display: none
  }

  img {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  /* Slideshow container */
  .slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
  }

  /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
  .dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 2px;
    color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: color 0.6s ease;
  }

  .active,
  .dot:hover {
    color: #cc3333;
  }

  /* Fading animation */
  .fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {
      opacity: .4
    }

    to {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }

  @keyframes fade {
    from {
      opacity: .4
    }

    to {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }

  /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {

    .prev,
    .next,
    .text {
      font-size: 11px
    }
  }
```

```html
<div style="border-top: 6px solid #cc3333;padding-bottom: 100px; padding-top: 100px" class="row highlight-phone">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="vidrow">
      <div class="vidcolumn slideshow-container">
        <div id="slide1" class="mySlides">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="vidcolumn">
        <div class="intro">
          <h2 style="text-decoration:overline;text-decoration-color: #cc3333;">How It Works</h2>
          <div id="dot" class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)">Learning Paths</div>
          <br>
          <span id="dot" class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)">Songs</span>
          <br>
          <span id="dot" class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)">Training</span>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-wi-red btn-pill" role="button" href="#">VIEW DEMO</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If only that were the case. while it fixes the other images loading in, the first image/link still are not active when the page is loaded. See here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0a5e0otl9j74nl6/Sequence%2003.gif?dl=0

Comment: @ridge Have you tried running my demo? It works just fine there and the first image shows. Try rechecking your code since I am guessing what caused this is outside the code you gave in this post.

Comment: I copied and pasted exactly what you wrote. Ill check again but there should be anything causing an issue! strange

Comment: @ridge I cannot help if I can't reproduce the issue. I am just guessing at this point but try erasing display:none in .MySlides{} class in your css.

Comment: heres my code as it stands. It definetly is something in here but the document is super long that I cant find anything wrong. Maybe I'm missing something

https://www.dropbox.com/s/osutyi7d141dm9a/index.html?dl=0

Comment: @ridge Did you make all of this in 1 index.html, don't ever do this since it will only confuse you like now for example. Always seperate your css and js into a different file and just call it in the html afterwards

Comment: I was forced to do this for this project as it was a redesign of an extreme sorts. I know how to format, believe me I don't want it to be like this.

Comment: Then dont... This will only hurt you in the future. Better start clean code and structure from scratch. I tried loading it and it took a whole 3 minutes to load, this could be a very big problem.

Comment: I will separate and call them in different documents, but for now I just need to see if there is an answer to my question regardless of the formatting. I apologize

Comment: @ridge After enduring the painful loading of your index.html, the solution is simple... Change line 3650 to <div id="slide1" class="mySlides" style="display:block"> emphasis on display:block. Try inspecting the page next time while developing code. Page inspection is a web developer's best friend. Also, I am doing this inline css only for the sake of awareness, do it in a style sheet ! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for that solution. I did something along those lines, but when I do that the text for that slide is not set as active. How would I go about doing that? Sorry for the slow index

Comment: im a fool haha. that was easy, just set the class to active. its almost as if you have to write html for something to work the way you want it to

Comment: @ridge That is why I suggested working with dev tools. If thats all sorted and done, press the answer button and upvote if you dont mind. Don't let any other experience the same problem. Have fun re-structuring your web page...